# Fast way to put images of 5 sizes in 5 drawable folder in Android Studio

Tags: 16.04, command-line, android

I have downloaded a zip **ic_add.zip** of material design icons. This zip contains folders hierarchy like this :

```
res --> drawable-hdpi    --> ic_add.png
    --> drawable-mdpi    --> ic_add.png
    --> drawable-xhdpi   --> ic_add.png
    --> drawable-xxhdpi  --> ic_add.png
    --> drawable-xxxhdpi --> ic_add.png
```

Now, my question is how can I put these 5 icons in their resp. folders inside myProject/res folder ?

i.e. icons inside `drawable-hdpi` should go into `myProject/res/drawable-hdpi`. Same for others. Right now I am picking one icon and putting inside its respective folder but it is too long process when there are many icons to copy. So, I want some **faster way** or **command** if possible. I am using **ubuntu 16.04**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that after extracting your archive into a folder named `zip`, you have the following directory structure:

```
$ tree -F
.
├── myProject/
│   └── res/
│       ├── drawable-hdpi/
│       ├── drawable-ndpi/
│       ├── drawable-xhdpi/
│       └── drawable-xxhdpi/
└── zip/
    ├── drawable-hdpi/
    │   ├── ic_add.png
    │   └── ic_del.png
    ├── drawable-ndpi/
    │   ├── ic_add.png
    │   └── ic_del.png
    ├── drawable-xhdpi/
    │   ├── ic_add.png
    │   └── ic_del.png
    └── drawable-xxhdpi/
        ├── ic_add.png
        └── ic_del.png
```

Then you can simply move all `*.png` files from all `drawable-*/` directories inside `zip/` into their respective `drawable-*/` directories inside `myProject/res/` using the following command:

```
for folder in zip/drawable-*/ ; do mv "$folder"/*.png "myProject/res/$(basename $folder)" ; done
```

It will loop over all `zip/drawable-*/` folders, compute the appropriate target directory by appending the last path component of the source folder to the `myProject/res/` path, and move all `*.png` files from the source folder to the target folder.

You can alter the shell globs and paths to fit your real environment.
You can replace `mv` with `cp` to copy the files instead of moving them.
You can write `mv -i` to get asked before any existing files get overwritten or `mv -n` to skip files that already exist and don't overwrite anything. The same switches exist for `cp`.

However, note that neither `mv` nor `cp` create missing directories, so make sure the target paths for each file exists already.